# Vue.js Render Template with Vue.js syntax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

### Data Variable

```
 var data = {
        template:`<div class="box-word-cent">
           <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
           <p>{{ desc }}</p>
         </div>`,

        content:{
           title:'This is Title',
           desc:'This is. Description'
        }
     }
```

### Vue

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: data
});
```

### Html

```
<div id="app">
     <div v-html="data.template"></div>
</div>
```

I try to separate content data from template, but it seems like not work.

any one can help to achieve this conception ?

Comment: Please add language hints so that your source code is displayed with highlighting.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML. You cannot use bindings in `v-html`

Comment: my idea is     saving   vue template to database for easy manipulate

Comment: @Phil   thanks, i've read it yesterday,  v-html cannot render vue template, but how to implement this idea ....  it bother me for 2 days...   T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var data = {
    template:`<div class="box-word-cent">
       <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
       <p>{{ desc }}</p>
     </div>`,

    content:{
       title:'This is Title',
       desc:'This is Description'
    }
 }
```

And

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    template: data.template,
    data: data.content
});
```

And just

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

This is an unusual way to write your Vue, however.

Comment: Looks good though you're missing a comma after `data.template` ~ https://jsfiddle.net/n24jo0dc/72/

Comment: @phil oops! Thank you.

Comment: @BertEvans  thank you,  it's work.   do you have any suggestion about saving template with vue syntax to database ?

Comment: @AirconChen I've never personally tried saving template to the database.